# How to share private file between applications without using share intent?

Tags: android

I need to create a private file that only my applications can access, so I followed this [approach](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) using android FileProvider to share the file Uri.
the problem is I don't need to share it using share Intents, I need the application that receives the Uri askes for it when it needs using any connections way like Socket or BroadcastReceiver.
I'm facing a problem when sending the intent with the broadcast reciever
The file creator app:

```
val contentUri: Uri = getUriForFile(this, AUTHORITY, myFile)
    grantUriPermission(RECIEVER_APP_PACKAGE_NAME, contentUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION and Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.apply {
        component = ComponentName(RECIEVER_APP_PACKAGE_NAME,"$RECIEVER_APP_PACKAGE_NAME.MyReciever")
        data = contentUri
        clipData = ClipData.newRawUri("", contentUri)
        addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
    }
    sendBroadcast(intent)
```

When onReceive triggered in receiver app

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onReceive: ${intent!!.data}")
    val parcelFileDescriptor = context!!.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(intent.data!!,"r")
}
```

I get

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider androidx.core.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{601211e 3719:com.test.reciverapp/u0a144} (pid=3719, uid=10144) that is not exported from UID 10143

any help or ideas?
My optimal scenario is to make shared dir between my applications only, that any app can create a file and other apps have full control over these files. or the second scenario that one app creates a file and the other can at read it.

Comment: You can use AIDL, Broadcast, Share Intent with packageName set to your app packageName. Also for permission Denial you have to add GRANT_PERMISSION flag

Comment: `When I receive the intent using BroadcastReciever like this` I wonder how you did send a broadcast for this.

Comment: @blackapps I updated the question, please take a look

Comment: @Amin I already granting the permission,   I updated the question, please take a look.
Actually, the same intent works when I useing it as share intent

Comment: Do not use FileProvider as it gives you this SecurityException. Write your own ContentProvider then you can do what you want. You can share the uri for a directory then and use .query() to provide a file list for that directory.

Comment: @blackapps I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have already found the solution, but since Android S is deployed now, many other may have problem with sharing files between application due to ScopedStorage restriction.

As the Developer Guide, the permissions will be granted properly if the intent is used to start Activity/Service. At this time, Android Framework may extract the permission from your sent Intent, and grant it to the target Activity/Service.

However, in BroadcastReceiver case, the intent is not used to start Activity/Service. It's only used to carry the Uri.

To solve this problem, we need to grant the permissions to target Application manually. You can simply use the following code:

```
yourContext.grantUriPermission("targetPackageName", uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

then the problem with permission will be solved.

Comment: What if I don't what to grant permission to a specific app? I want to open an intent chooser and then whoever application is opened for that intent I want the permission to be granted to that particular application only. Is there any such thing?

Comment: I guess chooser is the most common case, that is already guided in developer guide of Android(https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/share-file)

Comment: I already implemented the chooser intent but it did not work. So I posted a question with all the necessary code. Can you please take a look? Maybe you can help. [Here is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71183846/how-to-share-apps-private-files-via-intent)