# How to share app's private files via intent?

Tags: android, android-sharing

I am building a photo vault (that helps users hide photos) for Android 11 onwards since the birth of mighty "scoped storage" I am able to hide photos by just moving them to the app's private directory.

Now the problem arises when I want to share an image without moving it to the public (shared) directory.

I followed the implemented `FileProvider`, which converts the image path to URI but when I share the content URI via an intent, the following error pops up in logcat and the receiver application can not read the image.

```
Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri content://com.androidbull.incognito.vaultreborn.provider/photos/Screenshot_20211221-105658.jpg from pid=10376, uid=1000 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
```

Here is the code I wrote to perform sharing

```
    val imagePath = File(this.filesDir, "photos")
    val newImageFile = File(imagePath, currentImage.imageName)

    val imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "$packageName.provider", newImageFile)

//
    val shareContentIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    shareContentIntent.data = imageUri
    shareContentIntent.addFlags(
        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
    )
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareContentIntent, null))
```

and just in case you are wondering here is the my provider in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths">
        </meta-data>
    </provider>
```

And finally the `file_paths.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
<files-path
    name="photos"
    path="photos/" />
</paths>
```

Can anyone please help me here?

Thank you :)

Comment: `.... requires the provider to be exported..`

Comment: but exporting a FileProvider just crashes the app and says FileProvider should not be exported

Comment: "I am able to hide photos by just moving them to the app's private directory" -- from a programming standpoint, what do you mean by this? In other words, how are you obtaining the value shown as `this.filesDir` in your code? That needs to line up with what you have in `file_paths.xml`.

Comment: @CommonsWare moving photos to app-specific directory. The path of which can be obtained by `Context.filesDir`. Since that directory is specific for that particular app's only so that does the job of hiding photos from all other applications.

Comment: That all sounds fine, and there is nothing obviously wrong with your code here. Perhaps there is a bug in the receiving application. The error that you are seeing from the receiving application commonly comes from [mishandling the `Uri` that it receives](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare There is no particular receiver application in this case. It opens a chooser and lists all the qualifying applications and none of them is able to receive/read image.

Comment: Consider switching from creating the `Intent` yourself to using `ShareCompat.IntentBuilder`: https://commonsware.com/blog/2021/01/07/action_send-share-sheet-clipdata.html

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it turned out that there was a bug in my head, not in the code.
I was only testing it for the very first image that I moved into my vault, somehow this image was showing perfectly but had a file size of 0 bytes, so that was the problem. I tested other images and worked perfectly.

Thanks, everyone for paying attention :)